# Is Windows Azure cspack.exe open source?

Tags: java, windows, azure, sdk, cspack

I'm trying to pack my Java Azure project in Mac and I cannot find the source code for cspack.exe. So far, I've managed to run Azure Eclipse plugin and successfully created a project but when trying to deploy it cannot run cspack.exe.
I've downloaded Windows Azure Tools and seen CsPack.cs up to the following lines

```
// Run CsPack to generate the package
ProcessHelper.StartAndWaitForProcess(
  new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(AzureSdkBinDirectory, Resources.CsPackExe),
    args), out standardOutput, out standardError);
```

And I don't really know if this component it's open source or not.
If cspack.exe is proprietary, is there any way to simulate cspack.exe. I know it compresses the project to a zip file but I could use any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cspack.exe is not open source. It will is packed into the Azure SDK which can be downloaded and installed. There is something Open Source like jJack said, but this is only the API which can be used in a Java, .NET or whatever program, to get access to your configurations, mounting a cloud drive or something else.
The eclipse plugins is using a cspack.exe.jar, which is a commandline wrapper for the original cspack Application.
Azure SDK for Mac can be downloaded [Azure SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253471&clcid=0x409). Don't know if the Eclipse plugin is capable to work on Mac yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WindowsAzure4j is open source so if this is what you are using then you are in luck. I would try downloading [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javasdk-azure/files/) and look for the full CsPack.cs file, maybe you can glean the source of the problem from it?

Comment: WindowsAzure4j is obsolete. Microsoft open-sourced the officially-supported Java SDK, along with all other SDKs plus PowerShell tools, [here](https://github.com/windowsazure).